# Can i host my android apk to google playstore which is in bin without exporting as signed key?

Tags: android, google-play

I have hosted an app in google play store with out generating a signed key, directly from bin the apk file is uploaded to playstore.
Now i want to update that application in play store.?? any way that gets updated?,

Comment: I dont think that uploading unsigned apk file is allowed in play store

Comment: no u cannot update your app .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK uploading an unsigned application is not allowed to be uploaded to the play store - so I think your app is signed - you just might not know with which key. So find the right key and you will be able to update

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your apk is signed and then uploaded to the playstore. Without signing the application if you upload the apk directly from the bin,You would not be able to update your application in the playstore,and it is not the right way to upload apk.
GOto-->build-->export signed application package get the apk and put to playstore.